# Is Swindrik a liar?

Tags: ultima-4

Swindrik can be found hanging out on the east side of the Dueling Weapons/Armoury Limited shop in Trinsic, as shown below:

[image]

He tells the player to ask about mandrake root at the Folley Tavern in Paws. However, nobody at the Folley Tavern seems to know anything about mandrake root. I haven't been able to find an explanation for this online.

What gives? Is he full of it?

## Edit

Apparently I should be able to ask Greg or Rob about it, but the only thing I am able to ask them about is food or ale:

[image]

At this point, the game only accepts "A" or "F" as input. After paying, he asks "Somethin' else?" to which the player can respond "Y" or "N". Then the conversation repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to bribe the barkeep by paying him more than 2gp. I paid 4gp, at which point he asked "What do you want to know?" and I was able to ask him about mandrake root. He doesn't give any useful information until he receives additional bribes however. I ended up paying him 44gp total (4gp originally, then 20gp twice) before he would tell me.